# Meteor does not re-render after successful user authentication if user's cache is not warm

Tags: meteor

Steps to reproduce in our application:

1. Log out.
2. Clear the cache.
3. Reload the page.
4. Log in.
   Actual: You stay on the front page.
   Expected: The application opens.

Our main template shows the app if a user is logged in (specifically, `{{#if currentUser}}`). Otherwise, it shows a splash page where the user can create an account and log in.

We're using the `{{loginButtons}}` helper.

Would this be a use case for `Meteor.flush()`? How would I get that to trigger upon user login? `Meteor.autorun()`?

Comment: This is pretty surprising. Can you reproduce this in a pared-down example (ie, not your whole app) that others can look at?

Comment: ...potentially, but probably not at the drop of a hat. I'll edit my question and comment again when we get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple things that led to a solution here.

1. I restructured my front page template to take `{{loggingIn}}` into account. Before, I was only using `{{currentUser}}`.
2. I made sure I wasn't setting `Session` variables in template helpers, especially not those where I was also getting them in other code paths. This explains why the issue felt like a race condition and only happened with a "cold cache" as I put it.

Also, the reason the view wasn't changing was because of errors preventing it from doing so. So it was a symptom, not the actual problem (although I did need to improve the template conditions a bit).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the logic isn't actually in a template you've defined but rather in the index.html itself? I could see how that might cause issues if it hasn't been broken out into some sort of front page logic template from which you call the other templates. Just an idea.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work :( — still happens sometimes. Any other ideas?